# How does pandas calculate indexes?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, time-series

I want to include time series  data in a dataframe from a csv. I use the following procedure:

```
path = [r'C:\data_' + str(x) + ".csv" for x in range(1150, 1177)]
data_df = pd.concat(pd.read_csv(f, delimiter = ",", header = None) for f in path)

data_df.head()
```

[image: head]

And the result is like the following:

```
data_df.info()
```

[image: indexes]

How is it possible that indexes (1 to 187481) differ from number of rows (5387507 ) ?

Doing

```
data_df.reset_index()
```

things get normal:

[image: indexes corrected]

So how is the initial index calculated ?

Comment: try to use `ignore_index=True` in the `pd.concat()` call. Every call of `pd.read_csv()` generates it's own index for each CSV file and when you concatenate them - `pd.concat()` per default just copies them, so you'll have duplicates ...

Comment: thank you @MaxU for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are duplicates in `indexes`, because each `index` of `DataFrame` starts from `0` in `concat` function.

And as [MaxU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38269303/how-does-pandas-calculate-indexes/38269380#comment63958066_38269303) commented, solution is add parameter `ignore_index=True` to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) -  [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#ignoring-indexes-on-the-concatenation-axis):

```
data_df = pd.concat(pd.read_csv(f, delimiter = ",", header = None) for f in path, ignore_index=True)
```